# Dont Scale a Barcode

Tags: css, printing, barcode, barcode-printing

I have a barcode generated by a [Jquery Plugin](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html).

```
//Generate ID Barcode
$("#myid_info_barcode").barcode("101-03043", "code39");
```

HTML Output:

```
<div id= "myid_info_barcode"><img id="barcode"></div>
```

The output is different when I print it with a "Letter" Paper Size and CR80 Card. The Bars in CR80 Card is thinner, smaller and not functional. It seems that the barcode is being scaled down.

[image]

The barcode in the bond paper works well but the barcode in CR80 Card doesnt function. How will I make the barcode doesn't scale using css?

Comment: A common solution for printing accuracy is to generate a PDF and print the PDF.  HTML is not designed for exacting printing accuracy.  A PDF is designed for that.

Comment: @jfriend00 --> Thanks for giving me an idea. If you know some links that could help me do that, that would be great.